# R Mutate to create count on previous value

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm having difficulties with the following task and would like to ask for some help:

The task is to create a counter of how many days the product was not delivered consecutively, in the table it's the variable Delivered_Flag and my dataframe is called df:

| Item | Date | Delivered_QTY | Delivered_Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2/02/2021 | 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 3/02/2021 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 4/02/2021 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 5/02/2021 | 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 6/02/2021 | 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 7/02/2021 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 8/02/2021 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 9/02/2021 | 0 | 3 |
| 7 | 2/02/2021 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 3/02/2021 | 0 | 2 |
| 7 | 4/02/2021 | 1 | 0 |
| 7 | 5/02/2021 | 2 | 0 |
| 7 | 6/02/2021 | 5 | 0 |
| 7 | 7/02/2021 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 8/02/2021 | 0 | 2 |

My code looks like:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(item) %>% mutate(Delivered_Flag= case_when(Delivered_QTY !=0 ~ 0,                                                       
                         Delivered_QTY == 0 & lag(Delivered_Flag)==0 ~ 1,
                         Delivered_QTY== 0 & lag(Delivered_Flag)!=0 ~ lag(Delivered_Flag)+1,
                         TRUE ~ 1))
```

Opened a new fresh R session and this is the code:

```
library(dplyr)
item <- c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,7,7,7)
Date <- c("2/02/2021","3/02/2021","4/02/2021","5/02/2021","6/02/2021","7/02/2021","8/02/2021","9/02/2021","2/02/2021","3/02/2021","4/02/2021","5/02/2021","6/02/2021","7/02/2021","8/02/2021")
Delivered_QTY<- c(4,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,5,0,0)

df<- data.frame(item,Date,Delivered_QTY)

df <- df %>% group_by(item) %>% mutate(Delivered_Flag= case_when(Delivered_QTY !=0 ~ 0,                                                       
                         Delivered_QTY == 0 & lag(Delivered_Flag)==0 ~ 1,
                         Delivered_QTY== 0 & lag(Delivered_Flag)!=0 ~ lag(Delivered_Flag)+1,
                         TRUE ~ 1))
df
```

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Delivered_Flag`.
x object 'Delivered_Flag' not found
i Input `Delivered_Flag` is `case_when(...)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: item = 5.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Any help would be appreciate it.

Comment: It works with me... Would you try `dplyr::mutate`?

Comment: Works for me as well. Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) ?

Comment: I added the full code underneath with the error I'm getting

Comment: `case_when` doesn't seem to know what `Delivered_Flag` is, maybe because the column is not defined until the entire `case_when` process finish successfully. Would you be able to initialize `Delivered_Flag` somehow, so that `case_when` can use it in the conditions? Maybe with a previous `mutate()` and a `if_else(Delivered_QTY !=0, 0, 1)`.

Comment: @LeonardoHansa that worked in some extent,. Refer to the table but when item =5 and Date = 9/02/2021 the Delivered_Flag count should be 3 and this method gives a 2. This means that it's just adding a +1 to the previous value in the field but not as a counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make calls to Delivered_Flags before it exists. I rewrote your code a bit to make it look like this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(item, grp = cumsum(Delivered_QTY != 0)) %>%
  mutate(Delivered_Flags = case_when(first(Delivered_QTY != 0) ~ row_number() - 1,
                                     first(Delivered_QTY == 0) ~ as.numeric(row_number()))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)
```

Comment: Yes this works, thanks alot! Although I'm not fully sure of what is the cumsum function so will take a look.

Comment: The cumsum function makes a cumulative sum within a group. But instead of doing a cumsum on the quantity itself I do a cumsum over a boolean. It's a very convenient solution for such type of questions